# C - User input into a Matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to make a program in which the user first inputs the size of a matrix and then whether each cell is occupied(o) or unoccupied(.).  How would I write it so that the user enters a whole row of inputs for occupied/unoccupied, rather than cell-by-cell using nested for loops?

**UPDATE**

There is an example where items are entered one by one:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main(void)
{
    char matrix[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE] = { 0 };
    int rows = 0, cols = 0;
    while (rows < 1 || rows > MAX_SIZE)
    {
        printf("What is the number of rows? ");
        scanf("%d", &rows);
    }
    while (cols < 1 || cols > MAX_SIZE)
    {
        printf("What is the number of columns? ");
        scanf("%d", &cols);
    }
    // fill the matrix
    printf("Please, fill the matrix by entering o for occupied or . for unoccupied cell (E for exit)\n");
    int r, c, ch;
    int fulfill = 1;
    for (r = 0; r < rows && fulfill; r++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < cols && fulfill; c++)
        {
            // clean the input bufer
            while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
            // read data
            printf("cell [%d, %d] : ", r + 1, c + 1); // or just r, c if you prefer 0..(N-1) indexing
            while (matrix[r][c] != 'o' && matrix[r][c] != '.' && matrix[r][c] != 'E')
            {
                scanf("%c", &matrix[r][c]);
            }
            if (matrix[r][c] == 'E')
            {
                fulfill = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    // output
    printf("\nResult is:\n");
    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            printf("%c", matrix[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char** matrix; // now it is a pointer and memory will be allocated after getting values of rows and columns
    int rows = 0, cols = 0;
    while (rows < 1)
    {
        printf("What is the number of rows (should be >= 1)? ");
        scanf("%d", &rows);
    }
    while (cols < 1)
    {
        printf("What is the number of columns (should be >= 1)? ");
        scanf("%d", &cols);
    }
    // part 1 for memory allocation
    matrix = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * rows);
    // fill the matrix
    printf("Please, fill the matrix by entering o for occupied or . for unoccupied cell (other chars will be ignored)\n");
    int r, c, ch;
    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        // part 2 for memory allocation - memory for each row
        matrix[r] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * cols);
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            // read while apropriate character was found
            while ((ch = getchar()) != 'o' && ch != '.');
            // save character to matrix
            matrix[r][c] = ch;
        }
    }
    // output
    printf("\nResult is:\n");
    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            printf("%c", matrix[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    // free the memory
    for (r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        free(matrix[r]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

Here data is stored in the heap (dynamic memory, allocate by `malloc`, or other similar functions) and despite the use of the same nested loops entering is different. See, how it works:

```
What is the number of rows (should be >= 1)? 3
What is the number of columns (should be >= 1)? 3
Please, fill the matrix by entering o for occupied or . for unoccupied cell (other chars will be ignored)
o.o
.o.
o.o

Result is:
o.o
.o.
o.o
```

User can enter row by row using Enter key to start new row, or just type `o` and `.` one by one for all cells (filling will be row by row in any case). Unnecessary elements, as well as inappropriate chars (different from `o` and `.`), will be ignored. E.g.:

```
What is the number of rows (should be >= 1)? 4
What is the number of columns (should be >= 1)? 5
Please, fill the matrix by entering o for occupied or . for unoccupied cell (other chars will be ignored)
ooZooCooXooOoo
......
........XXX

Result is:
ooooo
ooooo
.....
.....
```

Comment: Hi, would static allocation be a viable option as well?  Also my code is assuming the user will enter the correct input (quantity and correct characters), so how would that change the example?  I am a beginner at C and was wondering if the code could be simplified.

Comment: I have added an example to the question, where array is static. You can use the same approach. If you have any question, ask with new post after you have your code

Comment: Even if user is always correct, some chars (e.g. `\n`) should be skipped. So be careful with code minimization. And if this answer is useful, accept it